# File preview opening in VS Code, closing all tabs opened at that time

Tags: visual-studio-code

The preview of a CSS sheet is opening up at random times. Here's an image:

[image]

Sometimes, it opens after saving the file. On other times, it opens when I start typing a new css rule. On other times, it opens without me clicking anything.

It is very annoying - the preview closes all tabs that I had opened in VS Code. It happens every couple of minutes.

Does anyone know how I could disable the preview from opening?

I have tried disabling different preview settings in VS Code, but none of them fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's the markdown preview feature. I can tell because of the way it renders the source file, and by the [image]/[image] icon in the editor tab handle. You get it when you run the `Markdown: Open Preview` command, which on Windows and Linux, is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

I'm not sure why it randomly pops up for you, and I'm not sure why it closes all your other tabs when it opens. That sounds like a bug, which you can report as an issue ticket to the VS Code GitHub repo. I tried a cursory google to see if similar issues have been reported before and didn't see anything that looks the same by googling "`github vscode issues markdown preview closes all other tabs`", "`github vscode issues markdown preview unexpected`", but then again, it was just a cursory google looking at the top few results.

The fact that you're getting it for a supposed CSS file might mean that the language mode is wrong, which is surprising because VS Code tends to be pretty good at guessing the language mode based on the contents of the file, and your file isn't small either. Maybe you accidentally changed the language mode to markdown. You can change it to CSS following the docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_change-the-language-for-the-selected-file.

> click on the language indicator - which is located on the right hand of the Status Bar. This will bring up the **Select Language Mode** dropdown where you can select another language for the current file.
>
> Tip: You can get the same dropdown by running the **Change Language Mode** command (`Ctrl+K M`).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.